# Oracle SQL Between Dates Query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I don't understand why my query is not returning anything:

```
 select * from emp where hiredate between to_date ('01/01/81',
 'mm/dd/yy') and to_date ('12/31/81', 'mm/dd/yy');
```

Here is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP ( 
EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL, 
ENAME CHAR(10), 
JOB CHAR(9), 
MGR NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT EMP_SELF_KEY 
REFERENCES EMP (EMPNO), 
HIREDATE DATE, 
SAL NUMBER(7,2), 
COMM NUMBER(7,2), 
DEPTNO NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT EMP_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO), 
CONSTRAINT EMP_PRIM_KEY PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO)); 

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,'17-NOV-1981',5000,NULL,10); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,'1-MAY-1981',2850,NULL,30); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,'9-JUN-1981',2450,NULL,10); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,'2-APR-1981',2975,NULL,20); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,'28-SEP-1981',1250,1400,30); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-FEB-1981',1600,300,30); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,'8-SEP-1981',1500,0,30); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,'3-DEC-1981',950,NULL,30); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-FEB-1981',1250,500,30); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,'3-DEC-1981',3000,NULL,20); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,'17-DEC-1980',800,NULL,20); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,'09-DEC-1982',3000,NULL,20); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,'12-JAN-1983',1100,NULL,20); 
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,'23-JAN-1982',1300,NULL,10);
```

Please help me understand. Thank you.

Comment: I think I know now why it is not returning any result -- it is because the year is vague, it doesn't know which year to return or it uses the current century that is why it is not giving any result. Just a thought.

Comment: I used the RR format and it returned results:

Comment: You are right. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40879

Comment: You just tried to reinvent the `Y2K` bug ;-)

Comment: @ddoctor you can post this as an answer. It's will surely get upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another difficulty with the statement in the OP

```
select * from emp where hiredate between to_date ('01/01/81',
 'mm/dd/yy') and to_date ('12/31/81', 'mm/dd/yy');
```

is that `hiredate` could contain a time part. Given the sample data, it doesn't, but there's nothing preventing it from happening. With that in mind, a better approach -- better than using `BETWEEN` -- would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM emp
 WHERE hiredate >= DATE'1981-01-01'
   AND hiredate < DATE'1982-01-01';
```

One could also use `TRUNC()`:

```
SELECT * FROM emp
 WHERE TRUNC(hiredate, 'YEAR') = DATE'1981-01-01';
```

I can't see any reason to use `TO_DATE()` now that Oracle supports ANSI date literals (since 9i).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the inputs.

Comment: The `TRUNC()` function will prevent index usage, unless there's a function-based index on `TRUNC(hiredate, 'YEAR')`...

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments you would need to use the `RR` format [as documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924), or probably better, use 4-digit year. Examples given by [Wernfried](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried) in the comments:

- `to_date ('01/01/81', 'mm/dd/rr')`
- `to_date ('01/01/1981', 'mm/dd/yyyy')`

However, I strongly suggest you do not use Oracle's formatting function if you don't really need to do any formatting. Write this instead:

```
select * from emp 
where hiredate between date '1981-01-01' and date '1981-12-31';
```

The above is the SQL standard way of expressing date literals, also supported by Oracle. It is much easier to remember than the formatting strings, and it is independent of your locale / language, etc.

If you're trying to do the same with timestamps, there are also timestamp literals:

```
where hiredate between timestamp '1981-01-01 00:00:00.0'
                   and timestamp '1981-12-31 23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: Just for completeness, (**non-preferred**) TO approach would be `to_date ('01/01/1981',
 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date ('12/31/1981', 'mm/dd/yyyy')` or (**even worse**) `to_date ('01/01/81',
 'mm/dd/rr') and to_date ('12/31/81', 'mm/dd/rr')`. However, both of them would work out.